# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'here' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have searched online for hours and haven't found anything that fixes my error. I have a file with this code,

```
<?php
   class Conn {
   public static $dbhost = “localhost”;
   public static $dbuser = " < provide here user name to your database> ";
   public static $dbpass = "< password you use to access database >";
   public static $dbname = " <database name> ";
   }
?>
```

and here's my error,
**Parse error:** `syntax error, unexpected 'here' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Registration/Conn.php on line 4`

I've tried changing " to ' yet it doesn't help!

I don't have any open strings, so what's the problem???

Comment: curly quotes are killing your code

Comment: That is the curly quotes in $dbhost=“localhost”

Comment: here copy/paste this `"localhost";` these types of questions are off-topic btw

Comment: http://ideone.com/V66mNp shows no problems after replacing curly quotes

Comment: For some reason I still get the error

Comment: ok, the issue is obvious `" < provide here user name to your database> ";` etc. why are you using those and how?

Comment: `unexpected 'here'` ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: What do u mean? I already found the solution, it was the curly quotes, you were correct, it's just that my browser wasn't updating.

Comment: [I said this **22 freaking mins.** ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149984/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-here-t-string-expecting-or#comment50310179_31149984). What am I, blowing bubbles here? You know what copy/paste is?

Comment: I'm sorry it's just that my browser wouldn't update

Comment: You shouldn't use Microsoft Word for coding

Comment: And remember to ping people if you want them to be notified of your post by typing an @ before their name. Like this: @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Mike Fred's on vacation, as of right..... *now*. He will not be responding until his return, if they let him leave that is ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can we at least leave a message at the beep?

Comment: @Mike Only if there's enough tape left in the machine. *Call me old-fashioned*. Those old things still work, by gum they do!

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here and guessing that @Fred-ii- is going to check StackOverflow even on vacation... It's in your *veins*!!

Comment: I hope you've managed to get it back on @Mike didn't. Had a great time ;-) cheers. (was back yesterday, and a well-needed one at that).

Comment: Awesome @Fred-ii-. Glad to here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your code example, you can see you are using two different types of quotation marks. "localhost" is wrapped in curly quotes (“”), and not normal quotes. ("") This is causing the parsing error.

The difference:

```
“localhost”
"localhost"
```

Comment: I tried yet it doesn't change the error!

Comment: Could you post the new code, as you did in your original post?

Comment: The error seems to be stemming from how you are using this class. What code is accessing these public members prior to the error being thrown?

Comment: Ok so my browser was apparently not updating the code, just had to quit and restart and it was all fixed, THANKS!!

Comment: That's great! Glad I could help. Be sure to mark this answer as accepted if this was the solution. :) Thanks!